# How to set input mask for window created by another application

Tags: xlib

I want to write client which receives all event from window which is created and managed by another client. [XSelectInput](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html) method allows to do it but I have not get `Window` object. I have only window id and I think that I have to create `Window` object and assign id to it. But I don't know how to do this. I can not find `Window` doc in google. I am Java developer and I am used to javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window (as almost any other X11 resource id) is just typedef to unsigned 32 bit int. Just cast your id to uint32

In X.h:

```
typedef unsigned long XID;
typedef CARD32 XID;
typedef XID Window;
```